# Avoid default activerecord primary index creation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to workout how to advise/tell activerecord not to create it's primary index by default.

Anyone know how i can achieve this ?

```
class CreateHouse < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :houses do |table|
      table.string :name, :null => false, :unique => true
      table.integer :number, :null => false, :unique => true
      table.string :category, :null => false
      table.timestamps(:null => false)
    end
    add_index :houses, [:category, :number], :unique => true
  end
end
```

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `id: false` to your `create_table` definition.  Try the following:

```
class CreateHouse < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :houses, id: false do |table|
      table.string :name, :null => false, :unique => true
      table.integer :number, :null => false, :unique => true
      table.string :category, :null => false
      table.timestamps(:null => false)
    end
    add_index :houses, [:category, :number], :unique => true
  end
end
```

**Update:**

Updated `create_table` and `add_index` block to use `:houses` symbol and not `:stores` as suggested by kengimel in an edit request (which apparently got rejected!).